# Can you help me prove $\exp(-x)=1/\exp(x)$?

Tags: exponential-function

> **Question.** Can you help me prove
> $$ \exp(-x)=\frac{1}{\exp(x)} \quad ? $$

I need to prove this for a maths homework. What's given is that

> 1. $ \displaystyle \exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} $.
> 2. $ \exp(1) = e $.
> 3. $ \exp(x+y) = \exp(x) \exp(y)$.

I managed to prove other terms but I can't do this, I've tried for hours. Sorry that I don't know how to properly write down the equation 1).

Comment: No other givens, like what $-x$ means?  This is slightly a provocative way to say it, but these extra things are actually important in some cases...

Comment: Also, it is recommended that the question you have should appear in the body of what you write, not just in the title.  A good way to do this might be to present an approach you might have taken to the problem.

Comment: I removed the inappropriate [tag:theorem-provers] tag – please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial and reference for formatting math on this site.

Comment: Is it given that $\rm{exp}(0)=1$? [If not it is not hard to show by plugging $x=0$ to the given series for $e^x.$] Once that is known, apply rule 3 in the case where $y=-x$ and you can derive what you need about $\rm{exp}(-x).$

Comment: What happens if you multiply $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ using the power series definition?

Answer (score 2):

The first relation provides $\exp(0) = 1$ by mere evaluation; the third one gives then :
$$
1 = \exp(0) = \exp(x-x) = \exp(x)\exp(-x) \verb+ +\Leftrightarrow\verb+ + \exp(-x) = \frac{1}{\exp(x)}
$$